# I want to make roles in a smart contract (whitelister, blacklister, owner) without using open zeppelin contract, any ideas?

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

I am developing a smart contract but I cant figure out a way to do this, what i have made so far is this thing.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

to simplify it:

```js
contract AccessControl {

    uint256 ADMIN_ROLE = 0;
    uint256 WHITELISTER_ROLE = 1;
    uint256 BLACKLISTER_ROLE = 2;

    mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => bool)) _roles;

    constructor() {
        _roles[ADMIN_ROLE][msg.sender] = true;
    }

    function setRole(uint256 role, address user, bool active) requiresRole(ADMIN_ROLE) {
        _roles[role][user] = active;
    }

    modifier requiresRole(uint256 role) {
        require(_roles[role][msg.sender], "AccessControl: Caller not allowed");
        _;
    }

}
```

This is basically what Openzeppelin's library is though.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you can do is wrap all of those mappings into a single map. Put your relevant data into a struct and make sure that it's efficiently packed so that you're saving on gas.

If a person can be assigned multiple roles, then you can use bitwise operations on some uint to represent those roles. For example, a uint8 can have 1 admin role and 7 other roles:
00000001 is an admin.
00000010 has role 1, maybe a whitelister.
00000100 has role 2, maybe a blacklister.
00000110 has both roles 1 and 2.

Of course, this is just one implementation. I believe I implemented something similar [here](https://github.com/upsilon-x/smart-contracts/blob/master/contracts/ServiceAccess.sol) if you do want to take a look.
Cheers.

Comment: thanks for the reply!! will check on it.